# Slider scrolls unlimited on click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, carousel

I would like to make a jQuery slider from scratch, everything is fine, but the problem is when you click on slider button fastly then, the slider image will scroll unlimited. And one more question is what common jQuery script will be used in this sliderBar from which we can be able to add this slider more than one time in a single page.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/37ao39y0/) and here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // recomended slider script start 
  $('.recommended_right_button').click(function() {
    $('.recommended_corousal_inner').animate({
      'margin-left': "-=200px"
    }, 1000);
    var rightMargin = parseInt($(".recommended_corousal_inner").css("margin-left"));
    if (rightMargin < -800) {
      $(".recommended_corousal_inner").stop();
    }

  });
  $('.recommended_left_button').click(function() {
    $('.recommended_corousal_inner').animate({
      'margin-left': "+=200px"
    }, 1000);
    var leftMargin = parseInt($(".recommended_corousal_inner").css("margin-left"));
    if (leftMargin > -5) {
      $(".recommended_corousal_inner").stop();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
/* ======recommended css start ========*/

.recommended_songs {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 240px;
  background: linear-gradient(#443535, #10282b 100%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4d4c4c;
}
.recommended_heading {
  color: #9ca1a2;
  font-family: 'museo_sans700';
  padding: 20px 10px 5px 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.recommended_heading a {
  color: #9ca1a2;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.recommended_heading a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.recommended_corousal {
  width: 940px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.recommended_corousal_inner {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 150px;
}
.recommended {
  width: 90px;
  height: 132px;
  background-color: #393535;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #443535;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.recommended:hover {
  border: 1px solid #625F5F;
}
.recommended_player {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
.recommended_player img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.recommended:hover .recommended_player {
  display: block;
}
.recommended_img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}
.recommended_img img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}
.recommended_movies_details {
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.recommended_movie_name a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px 0px 0px 10px;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'museo_sans700';
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: .5;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.recommended_movie_name a:hover {
  opacity: .9;
}
.recommended_left_button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 140px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  opacity: .6;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.recommended_right_button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.recommended_corousal:hover .recommended_left_button {
  display: block;
}
.recommended_corousal:hover .recommended_right_button {
  display: block;
}
.recommended_prev_button {
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.recommended_next_button {
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
/* ======recommended css end ========*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ===== recomended songs html start ================ -->
<div class="recommended_songs">
  <div class="recommended_heading"><a class="heading" href="#" title="new_releases">Recommended Songs</a>
  </div>
  <div class="recommended_corousal">
    <div class="recommended_corousal_inner">

      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--1-->

      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!--1-->
      <div class="recommended">
        <div class="recommended_player play_album">
          <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/4jlbe5lab/player_icon2.png" alt="player_image" title="Brothers" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_img">
          <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/l6vghyt7f/Brothers_2015_175x175.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="recommended_movies_details">
          <div class="recommended_movie_name">
            <a href="#" title="Brothers by Akshay kumar">Brothers bhai jaan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="recommended_left_button">
      <div class="recommended_prev_button">
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/69inu1mmp/prev_arrow.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="recommended_right_button">
      <div class="recommended_next_button">
        <img src="http://s23.postimg.org/nf1thw793/next_arrow.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ===== recomended songs html end ================ -->
```

Comment: when I push your slider button, nothing happens.

Comment: Only left arrow, but doesn't work. Cannot reproduce your situation.

Comment: @Jan_dh Plz take a look one more time carefully,,Everything runs fine.

Comment: @HenriS. Right Scroll the Result Bar on Jsfiddle.

Comment: just add a stop before your animate `.stop().animate({...})` on your clicks

Comment: @Rahul, doesn't work in Chrome & Firefox on OSX

Comment: @HenriS. Please Complete Scroll Right to the Result window on jsfiddle.

Comment: The reason why your animation just keeps going is because there are simple not enough pictures in your slider?  I click three times fast and it just moves three times?

Comment: Thanks. @PedroEstrada The unlimited slider problem is fixed. can i add a common jquery script from which more than one slider can be added in a page.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, when you bind the click event. use the jquery object `$(this)` inside the click event instead of pointing to all of the classes again.

Comment: @Rahul like so https://jsfiddle.net/37ao39y0/1/

Comment: Thanks..Very Much! @PedroEstrada